Do commuting operators also commute on a subspace?
I'm a little new to functional analysis and I have what feels like a basic question, but I fail to come up with a proof or counterexample.
Let $A$ and $B$ be bounded operators on a (potentially infinite-dimensional) Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. Let $P$ be the orthogonal projection onto a closed subspace of $\mathcal{H}$. Then the restricted versions of these operators acting on this subspace are given by $A_P=PAP$ and $B_P=PBP$. My question is as follows:
If $A$ and $B$ commute, do $A_P$ and $B_P$ commute? If not, is there a counterexample and are there any conditions under which they do commute? (e.g. $A$ and $B$ are self-adjoint, the closed subspace is finite, etc.) Or is there a different form of such restricted operators which do commute?

No, $A$ and $B$ do not necessarily commute, even in the finite-dimensional case, even when $A$ and $B$ are self-adjoint.
For instance, taking $\mathcal H = \Bbb C^3$, we have the counterexample
$$
A = \pmatrix{1 & 0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0}, \quad B = \pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0}, \quad P = \frac 13 \pmatrix{2&-1&-1\\-1&2&-1\\-1&-1&2}.
$$
I will leave it to you to verify that
$$
A_P B_P - B_PA_P = \frac 19\pmatrix{0&-1&1\\1&0&-1\\-1&1&0}.
$$
Each of the following conditions is sufficient to guarantee that $A_P$ and $B_P$ commute:

$AP = PA$,
$BP = PB$,
$P$ is a projection onto a 1-dimensional subspace.

Incidentally, the sufficiency of these conditions is enough to prove that there are no counterexamples where $\dim \mathcal H = 2$.
Another interesting observation here: if $U$ is an isometry such that $P = UU^*$ (for instance, if $U$ is the inclusion map from the image of $P$ to $\mathcal H$), then $A_P,B_P$ will commute iff $A_U, B_U$ commute, where
$$
A_U = U^*AU, \quad B_U = U^*BU.
$$
One useful feature of this characterization is that it makes condition 3 above much more obvious.
It might be useful to note that the operators $A_P,A_U$ may both be referred to as compressions of $A$.

Makes complete sense. Thank you so much for your help!
